# IQueryable.Select to a List type sub POCO

Tags: entity-framework, iqueryable

I have an Entity Framework model in which there is a "Customers" and a "CustomerPhones" table. A customer can have multiple phone numbers so the "Customer" entity has a collection of "Phone". I can query the model with no problem :

```
using (CustomerEntities context = new CustomerEntities())
{
    Customer customer = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault();
    CustomerPhone phone = customer.Phones.FirstOrDefault();

    MessageBox.Show(customer.Name + " " + phone.Number);
}
```

The model is too complex for what I need to do (even though my example is basic) so I'm trying to boil it down to simpler POCOs. Here are the 2 simple classes :

```
public class SimplePhone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleCustomer 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Phones is a list because a single Customer can have multiple phone numbers
    public List<SimplePhone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

I can populate the simple properties of the object using the "Select" method of "IQueryable" :

```
using (CustomerEntities context = new CustomerEntities())
{
   IQueryable<SimpleCustomer> customers = context.Customers.Select(
           c => new SimpleCustomer
           {
               Id = c.Id,
               Name = c.Name
           }
       );

   SimpleCustomer customer = customers.FirstOrDefault();

   MessageBox.Show(customer.Name);
}
```

So my question is pretty simple : how can I populate the "Phones" property which is a list?

```
using (CustomerEntities context = new CustomerEntities())
{
   IQueryable<SimpleCustomer> customers = context.Customers.Select(
           c => new SimpleCustomer
           {
               Id = c.Id,
               Name = c.Name
               Phones = ///????
           }
       );

   SimpleCustomer customer = customers.FirstOrDefault();
   SimplePhone phone = customer.Phones.FirstOrDefault();

   MessageBox.Show(customer.Name + " " + phone.Number);
}
```

Let me know if I'm unclear and/or you need more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there isn't something more to your question, but as far as I understand, you can just call `ToList` and it will be materialized as a list:

```
IQueryable<SimpleCustomer> customers = 
    context.Customers.Select(c => new SimpleCustomer
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name,
        Phones = c.Phones.Select(p => new SimplePhone 
                 {
                     Id = p.Id, // Unless you want the custom Id, i.e. c.Id
                     Number = p.Number
                 }).ToList();
    });
```

Comment: Yeah that was it (I sure feel a bit stupid now). Solution doesn't work for my actual project but at least I can start digging further knowing this works. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveRiley It happens to all of us!